# How do I allow only one user to su to another account?

Tags: sudo, su

I have user-a and user-b on my box.

How do I do a no-password `su - user-b` as user-a?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`su` is not meant to do that -- `sudo` is.

Open `/etc/sudoers.d/custom` and write the following:

```
user-a ALL=(user-b:user-b) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Which means: whenever *user-a* executes `sudo -u user-b` (or any other variant), let him go without asking for password.

Comment: That worked. All I needed to do than was 'sudo -u user-b bash'

Comment: "sudo -i -u user-b" worked aswell