# Allow nopasswd sudo for specific user

Tags: sudo, visudo

I am trying to set the scp as a specific user with NOPASSWD.

```
alice ALL = (bob:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/scp
```

As I did understand from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password/159009#159009?newreg=a8609fb68b7049cd9671213868e12cbf).
However when I save using my visudo I still can't run `sudo -u bob /usr/bin/scp bob@scp_client:upload_this_file`.

What should be included within the command to allow no password scp for alice as bob (but not as root).

Note: I did see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402832/how-do-i-allow-only-one-user-to-su-to-another-account), also I feel that everything is in the correct order in my sudoers file as I know about the order of commands like you can learn [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working).

The entire visudo file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    insults
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification
    # Dropped this as it doesn't really matter..

# User alias specification
    # Dropped this as it doesn't really matter..

# Cmnd alias specification
    # Dropped this as it doesn't really matter..

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# We have admin groups (Todo: make this smaller)
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Include the sudoers.d
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# One to rule all of them
alice ALL = (bob:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/scp
```

Comment: Are you sure the password being asked is by `sudo` and not by SSH?

Comment: Yes I have passwordless SSH with both alice and bob. I have verified this with `ssh alice@node ; ssh bob@node`

Comment: All that proves is that your current account has passwordless SSH, and says nothing about whether bob's account has passwordless SSH to bob's account on `node`.

Comment: Indeed I stand corrected, I did the following:
 - As alice I did `ssh bob@node`
 - As alice I did `sudo -s` to get a rootshell, and promote myself to bob with `sudo -u bob -s`.
 - As bob I did `ssh bob@node`

Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to `sudo -u bob -- ssh bob@node`
Seems that `sudo` was passing the `scp` commands.