# Create user with access to other users

Tags: permissions, login, users

Our team is 3 people :

- `anna`
- `ben`
- `carl`

They do web development so each site has its own user :

- `site1` is a user for website #1
- `site2` is a user for website #2

We want each user to login with their user and be able to `su` into the website's user so that files are created by the right "website" user.

Our twist is that every person must be able to `su` into websites' users but not into people's users. So `anna` can `su` to `site1` but she cannot `su` to `carl`.

Users (people) must be able to `su` into future websites' users (e.g. `site96` that does not exist yet). Note that people are pretty stable so it could be manageable to exclude instead of including.

When a website user is created, its group is the same as the user (user `site1` is only member of group `site1`). The server is managed by Runcloud, a service that generates the user and the group (same name for both).

I've seen articles like this which I think can help... but I get nowhere :

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-user-to-sudoers-in-ubuntu/

[How do I allow only one user to su to another account?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402832/how-do-i-allow-only-one-user-to-su-to-another-account)

Is this achievable by doing the right configuration once (and not alter it each time we create a new website) ?

Comment: No need to use `su` and no need to make the humans admins. this seems a classic use case for [groups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136788). Simply have the admin add each human to the `site1` *group*, `site2` *group*, etc. Many possible variations both simple and complex.

Comment: `su` or `sudo`?

Comment: what user @user535733 says. This is done with GROUPs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot control the groups. I have added a clarification about that.